# What's wrong with this wordpress SQL query?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have this query on a WordPress site:

```
SELECT post.*,postr.* 
FROM `wp_posts` as post 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships postr on post.ID=postr.object_id 
WHERE postr.term_taxonomy_id IN(".$implode.") 
AND post_status='publish' 
AND post_type='product' 
GROUP BY ID
```

where $implode is a string of 3 numbers (ex: 4,5,23).

The problem I'm having is that these numbers are being taken from the selection IDs for 3 drop down lists, but only one at a time seems to work for filtering. For example 4,3,21 will return the same as 4,0,0 and 0,5,0 will return the same as 0,5,25. What is wrong with my query? Is IN not appropriate here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add postr.term_taxonomy_id to the group by section, and you will get:

```
SELECT post.*,postr.* 
FROM `wp_posts` as post 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships postr on post.ID=postr.object_id 
WHERE postr.term_taxonomy_id IN(".$implode.") 
AND post_status='publish' 
AND post_type='product' 
GROUP BY ID,postr.term_taxonomy_id
```

It is because 'postr.term_taxonomy_id' is nonaggregated column and should be in group by.

Comment: Why does it not working? Which error does it give? You need to make some debug to learn this. For example, copy the SQL query and run it directly in phpmyadmin or another sql manager. (just replace $implode with real numbers) You will see raised error if there is one. I run this query in my localhost, it works without any error.

Comment: Hi, your code is executing is fine, but it's not doing what I need it to. Each of the three numbers in the IN statement are supposed to be filtering the results. Think for example of a country search query (Country, province, city) where each of the 3 values are filtering the results further. Right now it doesn't matter if the province changes, it will always show the results of just the first value (country)

Thanks.

Comment: yes, i just wrote the fix for wrong syntax. but logically, you need another approach. IN is not appropriate here, yes.

Comment: Using 3 inner joins would solve your problem. 

SELECT post.*,postr.* 
FROM `wp_posts` as post 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships postr on post.ID=postr.object_id 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships postr2 on post.ID=postr2.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships postr3 on post.ID=postr3.object_id 
WHERE postr.term_taxonomy_id=4 and postr2.term_taxonomy_id=5  and postr3.term_taxonomy_id=23 
AND post_status='publish' 
GROUP BY ID,postr.term_taxonomy_id